# bash script code inside C program

Tags: c, bash, quoting

my problem is the following: I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

 IFSBAK=$IFS
 if [ "$TXTEXT" = "" ]; 
 then
   CMD="find . -iname \"*.txt\" -or -iname \"*.text\""
 else
CMDTEMP="find . "
IFS=":"
for i in $TXTEXT
do
    CMDTEMP="${CMDTEMP} -iname \"*.${i}\" -or"
done
IFS=$IFSBAK
CMD=${CMDTEMP%-or}
 fi

 FILES=$(eval $CMD)
 OUTPUT=$1

 for f in $FILES
 do
VAR=$(grep -ae [a-zA-Z0-9] "$f" | tr -cs "[:alnum:]" "\n")
IFS=$' \n\t-?=!*][.\",();\'\`\´:'   
for v in $VAR
do
    echo $v >> "${OUTPUT}"
done
IFS=$' \n\t'
 done
```

and I need to insert this code inside a C program. I've tried to re-write the all script on a single line testing it directly with the shell and it works, but I'm having problems with quotes and escaping trying to use it as a parameter of the system() call.
Can you suggest me a way out?

Thank you for your help

Comment: seems like a mighty bad idea to insert that much shell code into binary

Comment: +1 @Anycom - anytime you think you need to do something like embed a 30 line shell script in your program, you need to rethink your design.

Comment: i already know it's an horrible thing to do, but i am forced to do it as requested. thank you anyway

Comment: How exactly are you forced to do this? Is the requirement really that absolute and specific, or is it indirect? There might be other ways, depending...

Answer (score 4):

If you really have no choice but to deliver a single binary and you cannot ship the shell script file with the binary consider the following:

1. Include the contents of the script in a single literal
2. During execution of the program, print the contents of the literal to a temporary file. You probably need some strategy to come up with a unique filename.
3. Call the temporary script through `system()` call
4. Delete the temporary file

However, consider this as a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

Put it into a shell script and invoke the shell script from your C code. Much easier to maintain IMHO.

Comment: How would you access functions in a Linux shell script from C code?

Comment: @abc You can't. You call the shell script as an external executable and then read the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "
...
write your shell script code here
...
"



   int main()
    {

        system(SHELLSCRIPT);
        return 0;
        //put the bash to C program 
    }
```